# Rails: Best way to allow a user to set a default resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a users and venues model. venues belongs_to users and users can have_many venues.

I would like a user to be able to set a default venue. I am new to programming/development and am keen to learn best practices.

So, should a venue have a boolean 'default_venue' column which only allows one row to be 'true' per user. Or should I be creating a default_venue model? And if so, any tips on what/how this would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just add a `default_venue_id` to the Users table. Then write a small method on the User model.

```
# User.rb
...blah blah validations
...blah blah other code

def default_venue
  Venue.where(id: default_venue_id)
end
```

Then going forward in your Controllers (or Rails Console), this would be valid code:

```
#Returns default venue for User
User.find(:id).default_venue
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a play around with this and see how I get on. Hadn't thought to put it on the user. I will also need to get my head around setting a default default venue (i know!) so that the first venue they add is the default. Thank you.

Comment: could I use current_user.default_venue (I am using Devise). What is the advantage of using User.find(:id) ?

Comment: You could absolutely use ```current_user.default_venue``` and it would be the better way to go since you are using devise. I wasn't sure if you were using devise or not, so I made my answer more generic.

Comment: Also, if you liked this answer, please consider marking it correct. Thanks!